# SQL запрос выполняется слишком медленно

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, процедуры

Есть база данных о студенте с таблицами вида: id, какой-то атрибут (например фамилия), дата добавления этого атрибута.Таких таблиц куча: для имени, роста, веса, зачетки.

Есть хранимая процедура, которая ищет на заданную дату информацию о студенте.

```
create or replace function hran_test2(d date) returns setof record as 
$body$
begin
return query select fam.id_stud,fam, nam, otc,rost
            from
            --Таблцица с фамилией
            (SELECT id_stud, fam 
             FROM (
                    select a.id_stud,fam
                    from (
                            select id_stud, dat,fam, abs(dat - d) as div
                            from stud_fam
                         ) as a
            inner join
                        (
                         select id_stud, min( abs(d-dat)) as mindiv 
                         from (select id_stud,dat 
                               from stud_fam 
                               where dat <= d) as c
                         group by id_stud
                        ) as b
            on a.id_stud = b.id_stud and a.div = b.mindiv) as k) as fam
            inner join
            --Таблцица с именем
            (SELECT id_stud, nam 
             FROM (select a.id_stud,nam
            from (
                    select id_stud, dat,nam, abs(dat - d) as div
                    from stud_nam
                 ) as a
            inner join 
                        (
                         select id_stud, min( abs(d-dat)) as mindiv 
                         from (select id_stud,dat 
                               from stud_nam 
                               where dat <= d) as c
                         group by id_stud
                        ) as b
            on a.id_stud = b.id_stud and a.div = b.mindiv) as k) as nam
             on fam.id_stud = nam.id_stud

            inner join
            --Таблцица с отчеством
            (SELECT id_stud, otc 
             FROM (select a.id_stud,otc
            from (
                    select id_stud, dat,otc, abs(dat - d) as div
                    from stud_otc
                 ) as a
            inner join 
                        (
                         select id_stud, min( abs(d-dat)) as mindiv 
                         from (select id_stud,dat 
                               from stud_otc 
                               where dat <= d) as c
                         group by id_stud
                        ) as b
            on a.id_stud = b.id_stud and a.div = b.mindiv) as k) as otc
             on otc.id_stud = nam.id_stud
            inner join

            --Таблцица с ростом
            (SELECT id_stud, rost 
             FROM (select a.id_stud,rost
            from (
                    select id_stud, dat,rost, abs(dat - d) as div
                    from stud_rost
                 ) as a
            inner join 
                        (
                         select id_stud, min( abs(d-dat)) as mindiv 
                         from (select id_stud,dat 
                               from stud_rost
                               where dat <= d) as c
                         group by id_stud
                        ) as b
            on a.id_stud = b.id_stud and a.div = b.mindiv) as k) as rost
            on otc.id_stud = rost.id_stud;
 end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Так вот эта хранимка выполняется за 300мс.

Видно что для каждой из таблиц (фамилии, отчества, имени итд.) код почти одинаковый и меняется только имя атрибута и имя таблицы.
Поэтому я создал вспомогательную функцию чтобы сократить код.

```
create or replace function getTable(col varchar(10),tab varchar(10),d    date) returns setof record as 
 $body$
 begin
 return query execute 'select a.id_stud,'||col||'
            from (
                    select id_stud, dat,'||col||', abs(dat -$1) as div
                    from '||tab||'
                 ) as a
            inner join 
                        (
                         select id_stud, min( abs($1-dat)) as mindiv 
                         from (select id_stud,dat 
                               from '||tab||' 
                               where dat <= $1) as c
                         group by id_stud
                        ) as b
            on a.id_stud = b.id_stud and a.div = b.mindiv' using d;
 end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

В итоге вот такая хранимая процедура выполняется за 120 мс!! Гораздо быстрее.

```
create or replace function hran_test1(d date) returns setof record as 
$body$
begin
return query select fam.id_stud,fam, nam, otc, rost
            from
            --Таблцица с фамилией
            (SELECT id_stud, fam 
             FROM getTable('fam','stud_fam',d) 
             as t(id_stud integer, fam varchar(40))) as fam
            inner join
            --Таблцица с именем
            (SELECT id_stud, nam 
             FROM getTable('nam','stud_nam',d) 
             as t(id_stud integer, nam varchar(40))) as nam
             on fam.id_stud = nam.id_stud
            inner join
            --Таблцица с отчеством
            (SELECT id_stud, otc 
             FROM getTable('otc','stud_otc',d) 
             as t(id_stud integer, otc varchar(40))) as otc
             on otc.id_stud = nam.id_stud
    inner join
    --Таблцица с ростом
            (SELECT id_stud, rost 
             FROM getTable('rost','stud_rost',d) 
             as t(id_stud integer, rost real)) as rost
            on rost.id_stud = otc.id_stud;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Планы выполнения посмотрите, вполне возможно на большом цельном запросе у оптимизатора сносит крышу от обилия таблиц. А вообще надо менять структуру базы. Хранить каждый отдельный атрибут в отдельной таблице неправильно и ведет вот как раз к написанию такого громоздкого, непредсказуемого кода

Comment: Изначально может строится не оптимальный план, например, используются индексы там где фул-скан эффективнее.

Comment: а этот план можно как-нибудь настроить? Посмотреть знаю как - EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи EXPLAIN ANALYZE сравнил планы выполнения. Оказалось, что они совершенно разные. В первом случае использовались seq_scan и nested_loop. 
Во втором всякие mergejoin и hashjoin.
Поэтому нашел [тут](http://wiki.etersoft.ru/PostgreSQL/Optimum#.D0.9E.D0.BF.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.8B_PostgreSQL) опции для оптимизатора.
Перед первым запросом поставил

```
SET enable_seqscan = false;
SET enable_nestloop = false;
```

Теперь платы выполнения стали схожими, а время одинаковым)

Answer (score 1):

у вас запросов в первом варианте больше чем во втором (вложенных)  , подсчитайте сколько в первом варианте SELECT FROM и во втором. Перед запросом #1 и #2 напишите EXPLAIN запустите и посмотрите какие индексы используются.

Индексы проставлены верно на все используемые колонки?

Избегайте вложенных запросов (рекомендую использовать это правило по возможности всегда ) заменяйте вложенные запросы на Join-ы

а зачем вам 4е таблицы..что одной фамилии может соответствовать два имени?...или одному имени соответствовать два роста и два отчества?..структура БД - неверная...

Comment: Сравнил EXPLAIN у этих запросов. Оказались совершенно разные. Нарыл что в Postgresql можно корректировать работу оптимизатора при помощи вот такой штуки:
#enable_seqscan = true
#enable_indexscan = true
#enable_tidscan = true
#enable_sort = true
#enable_nestloop = true
#enable_mergejoin = true
#enable_hashjoin = true

Comment: У первого запроса поставил:
SET enable_seqscan = false;
SET enable_nestloop = false;
Теперь запросы выполняются за одинаковое время.
Насчет проектирования БД. Я использовал 6НФ ([ссылка](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form)) . Она используется для хронологических БД. Т.е вполне возможно что будет два роста и два имени у одного человека.